# How do you stop users directly accessing files on a website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, windows-server-2012

I want to stop users on the internet being able to enter this URL into a browser and access these files directly. How can I do this?

note: application developed in asp.net

for example: mysite/uploadedfiles/file1.txt

is there any iis rule? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [requestFiltering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments/index) and hidden segments security feature in web.config.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <requestFiltering>
            <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="false">
               <add segment="uploadedfiles" />
            </hiddenSegments>
         </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be not to store these files in a location which is accessible via a URL in the first place. Then the problem is solved without worrying about permissions etc.

Once the user has uploaded the file, you can store it in some other place on the server's disk - no need for it to be within the web application.

And if the file must be downloadable again later, you can write an action method to find the necessary document on disk and transmit a copy of it in the response, without the webserver ever having direct access to it.